# List of List to 2-dimensional string

Tags: java

I have a dynamic list of list defined by

```
List<List<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

like:

```
[[A, B, C, D], [E, F, G, H]]
```

in this example it has 2 group of 4 items each but it can have 1 group to n groups dynamically.

Now, I need a 2-dimensional string, so something like:

```
String[][] data ={{"A", "B", "C", "D"}, {"E", "F", "G", "H"}}
```

exist a way to convert it easily? If not, how can I create dynamically a 2-dimension `String` where I know the number of column but not the rows?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this using streams. It streams the list and converts each inner list to an array and then converts those two arrays to an array of array.

```
List<List<String>>  list = List.of(
                List.of("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                List.of("E", "F", "G", "H"));
String[][] arr = list.stream()
             .map(lst->lst.stream()
                     .toArray(String[]::new))
             .toArray(String[][]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

Prints

```
[[A, B, C, D], [E, F, G, H]]
```

You could also do it this way.

```
String[][] arr = new String[list.size()][];
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    arr[i] = list.get(i).toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My proposal

```
private String[][] toMatrix(List<List<String>> listOfLists) {
    int size = listOfLists.size();
    String[][] result = new String[size][];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        List<String> list = listOfLists.get(i);
        result[i] = new String[list.size()];

        for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
            result[i][j] = list.get(j);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem here is that I want a result with a 2-dim string with 4-elements for each group.

NOT String[][] data ={"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"}
BUT String[][] data ={{"A", "B", "C", "D"}, {"E", "F", "G", "H"}}

Comment: That is what the method `toMatrix` returns - `String[][]` (two pair of brackets). The type for this `{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"}` is one dimension array - `String[]` (one pair of brackets).

Comment: Ok fine but the items in the String[][] are not in group of 4 items each. Am I wrong?

Comment: ```String[][] strings = toMatrix(list);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(strings));```
I get result 
```[[A, B, C, D], [E, F, G, H]]```

Comment: What I want as final result is assign to DATA_TO_SHOW my listOfLists in the correct format. Your code is fine for that? Sorry but I'm a newby for these kind of things


String[][] DATA_TO_SHOW = { { "This", "is", "a", "test" }, { "and", "a", "second", "test" } };

Comment: I think so. You should try it, and check the outcome.

Comment: Solved. Sorry but I was lost in a very stupid thing on my mind. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
private static String[][] convert(List<List<String>> listOfLists) {
    var result = new String[listOfLists.size()][];

    var i = 0;
    for (var list : listOfLists) {
        result[i] = new String[list.size()];
        var j = 0;

        for (var elem : list) {
            result[i][j] = elem;
            j++;
        }

        i++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: For some reasons my android studio doesn't recognize "var" sadly

Comment: `var` is a new Java keyword added in Java 10. Just replace var with `String[][]`